# "Where" is not working in select query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my code showing all the results with geolocation

```
$jobs = Job::select(
            DB::raw("*, status,
                          ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( latitude ) )
                            * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->having("distance", "<", "?")
            ->setBindings([$service->latitude, $service->longitude, $service->latitude, 30])
            ->with(['user'])
            ->orderBy("id", "desc");

        $jobs = $jobs->simplePaginate(10);
```

But the above code is not working with "where" like below and giving me an empty array

```
$jobs = Job::select(
            DB::raw("*, status,
                          ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                            cos( radians( latitude ) )
                            * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                            ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                            sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                          ) AS distance"))
            ->having("distance", "<", "?")
            ->setBindings([$service->latitude, $service->longitude, $service->latitude, 30])
            ->with(['user'])
            ->where("status", 3)   // not working
            ->orderBy("id", "desc");

        $jobs = $jobs->simplePaginate(10);
```

Comment: Your query looks good to me. Does your jobs table have a status eloquent and are there records with status id = 3 and deleted_at = null?

Comment: Try ->where("status", "=", 3). Sometimes the '=' is required depending on the type of query. Don't ask me to verify this, I don't know why, it just worked *sometimes*.

Comment: Have you tried to output the SQL of this query with the `->toSql()` method? Perhaps something is not where it should be.

Comment: @namelivia Yes, the records have "status" column with value 3

Comment: @BrandonKiefer , I've tried it but not working

Comment: Try moving `where` to the beginning so `Job::where('status', '=', 3)->select(...)`. And can you post the `->toSql()` version so we can look at the raw query?

Comment: @BrandonKiefer In the query, it is printing the correct query. But i dont know why it is not working? But in phpmyadmin that same query is working fine

Comment: Can you please add the raw SQL query so I can take a look at it?